# Google desktop logo looks bad

Tags: appearance, style, google-desktop

The Google Desktop icon in the system tray in Unity looks ugly:

[image]

Any way around this?

Comment: By the way if anyone wants to re-tag this question as "google-desktop" feel free. (I can't create tags yet)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this issue too, but fpoehler ( http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=1174921 ) solved it here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1466473&page=4 .

"
The themes that work should be the ones which have the same panel background as normal application windows. That's why the problem is not apparent there. However, newer themes often use a different color or a background image for the panel.
 

 
The fix is to apply the panel's properties (background color or background image) to GtkPlug widget class, which is not considered in most stock themes.
 

 
Steps:
 
1) Find out your panel's background color or the path to its background image (in case it has one).
 
For the color the hexadecimal value is needed (e.g. "#A1B2C3).
 
The image in most cases resides in /usr/share/themes/<Your_Theme's_Name>/gtk-2.0/ or a subfolder of that.
 

 
For Radiance theme it is

```
/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-2.0/apps/img/panel.png
```

2) (In case there is a background image) copy the background image to your home folder (or a subfolder of your home folder).

3) Open (or create) the file named ".gtkrc-2.0" in your home folder.
4) Copy the following into the file:

```
style "GoogleDesktopIconFix" {
    # In case your panel has a background image, add this line
    bg_pixmap[NORMAL] = "subfolder/panel.png"     # replace "panel.png" with the actual file name or (relative) path

    #In case your panel has no background image, add this line
    bg[NORMAL] = "#000000"              # replace "#000000" with your color value
}
class "*oPlug"    style "GoogleDesktopIconFix"
```

5) Open a terminal and type 
    
Code:

```
pkill gnome-panel
```

"

Results:
[image] (color)                                                 [image] (Background)

ps.: if it doesn't work:
1) Change  **class "*oPlug"** for **class "GtkPlug"**
2) Put the "relative" path to the background (example: if I put the background image at **"~/gdesk/panel.png"** I had to put the path **"gdesk/panel.png"**)

Comment: This works like a charm!!! http://i.imgur.com/iYVeP.jpg Thank you very much! +1 and accepted answer!

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I did not understand what you mean by `put the content of your file ~/.gtkrc-2.0`

Comment: @desgua This is what I have on the file: http://pastie.org/1724721

Comment: @desgua It is not `File system` it says I don't have the permission

Comment: @desua I have tried all the combinations I can think of for the path: `~/trufa/gdesk/panel.png`,`home/trufa/gdesk/panel.png`, `home/trufa/gdesk/panel.png` but no luck, could I be doing something else wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @desgua yes I did...

Comment: The site works better if you continuously update your question and answer whilst documenting what you are trying, otherwise things get buried in the comments.

Comment: @Jorge I will, you are right! sorry about that.

Comment: It's ok, it can be tough to get used to. I recommend you start documenting what you've tried so far in your question, the desgua can adapt his answers.