# How to fix the Google desktop logo in the notification area?

Tags: appearance, notification-area

Related: [Google desktop logo looks bad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32149/google-desktop-logo-looks-bad)

In my previous question I was helped to solve this appearance problem, thought this is solved:

[image]

I still don't really like how it looks since the white contrasts too much.

Is it possible to change this image, so that it looks like this:

[image]

<sub>Thanks [@desgua](https://askubuntu.com/users/12943/desgua) for the artwork</sub>

I do clarify that I just want in working for this ([image]) background color.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I thought it was solved? 
Would you please put the content of your file ~/.gtkrc-2.0 ?

Comment: Ohh but this is different issue, the first one was about the little stick in the middle of the image, now I mean the image itself... I don't know if I'm expressing the problem correctly!

Comment: I think you want something like this: <img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4098082/lcoP8.png width="140" height="51">

Comment: @desgua Images don't work in comments. Just post a link to it and you're fine.

Comment: @Octavian Damiean Thank you so much. I've been struggling to resolve this.

Comment: @Octavian and @desgua thanks!! I've edited my question to try and make it more comprehensible.

Comment: @Trufa: the tutorial in the other question should have addressed this issue too. Would you please put the content of your file ~/.gtkrc-2.0 ? May be I can help further.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too, but fpoehler ( http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=1174921 ) solved it here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1466473&page=4 .

"
The themes that work should be the ones which have the same panel background as normal application windows. That's why the problem is not apparent there. However, newer themes often use a different color or a background image for the panel.
 

 
The fix is to apply the panel's properties (background color or background image) to GtkPlug widget class, which is not considered in most stock themes.
 

 
Steps:
 
1) Find out your panel's background color or the path to its background image (in case it has one).
 
For the color the hexadecimal value is needed (e.g. "#A1B2C3).
 
The image in most cases resides in /usr/share/themes/<Your_Theme's_Name>/gtk-2.0/ or a subfolder of that.
 

 
For Radiance theme it is

```
/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-2.0/apps/img/panel.png
```

2) (In case there is a background image) copy the background image to your home folder (or a subfolder of your home folder).

3) Open (or create) the file named ".gtkrc-2.0" in your home folder.
4) Copy the following into the file:

```
style "GoogleDesktopIconFix" {
    # In case your panel has a background image, add this line
    bg_pixmap[NORMAL] = "subfolder/panel.png"     # replace "panel.png" with the actual file name or (relative) path

    #In case your panel has no background image, add this line
    bg[NORMAL] = "#000000"              # replace "#000000" with your color value
}
class "*oPlug"    style "GoogleDesktopIconFix"
```

5) Open a terminal and type 
    
Code:

```
pkill gnome-panel
```

"

Results:
[image] (color)                                                 [image] (Background)

ps.: if it doesn't work:
1) Change  **class "*oPlug"** for **class "GtkPlug"**
2) Put the "relative" path to the background (example: if I put the background image at **"~/gdesk/panel.png"** I had to put the path **"gdesk/panel.png"**)

Comment: nope, no luck! :(

Comment: no apparent changes see: http://i.imgur.com/2d236.png

Comment: @desgua important update, I add a new launcher It look good but I can't remove the one that looks bad see: http://i.imgur.com/fBlq1.png maybe it has something to do with the separator rounded by the red circle? Tahnks fot going through all the trouble!

Comment: Yes, it has something to do with the separator because it is an icon at the "Notification Area". I will dig more for a solution and post here.

Comment: @desgua you've been very kind, thank you for all the effort!

Comment: Welcome. It is a pleasure try to help. I didn't give up yet ;-)

Comment: See the related post http://askubuntu.com/questions/32149/google-desktop-logo-looks-bad I think I've found a fix.

Comment: Did you manage it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's under Post #36 by fpoehler. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1466473&page=4